# Is there a way to find out who is remote debugging on Glassfish?

Tags: debugging, glassfish

In our team someone is using the remote debugging on Glassfish.
Can I figure out which ip it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask the underlying operating system about open socket connections and locate the one corresponding to the GlassFish debug port.  You will then have the IP-number, which hopefully will allow you to identify the culprit.

The utility is commonly named "netstat".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Thorbjørn :) We now use the command

```
netstat -pnl | grep 9009
```

to figure out if Glassfish is listening for remote debugging
and `netstat -pn | grep 9009` to figure out who is currently using remote debugging